# django static files - don't work

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

I have a django project and I'm using static files, but it didn't work and i can not include my css file or my image to HTML file

here

```
<link rel="icon" href={% static "img/favicon.png" %}>
```

or

```
<link href={% static "css/mine.css" %} rel="stylesheet">
```

I checked my direction and everything is OK but i cant understand why my code didn't work

I also add static section in my **settings.py** as follows

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change like this

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static "img/favicon.png" %}">
```

and

```
<link href="{% static "css/mine.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: you forget to add `"` !! `"{% static "img/favicon.png" %}"` . you do like this : `{% static "img/favicon.png" %}`. it's wrong